# Ansible templates with timestamps

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to figure out if there's way of adding a timestamp to a template file in Ansible so that everytime I run an Ansible playbook which uses a certain template, it adds in the destination file the time of the execution of the playbook.

For example, I'm templating a configuration file with Ansible and I want it on the destination machine to appear with a timestamp on the first line...

e.g.

```
cat something.conf_template
some config lines
```

After templating:

```
- template: src=/mytemplates/something.conf_template dest=/etc/something.conf owner=smth group=smth mode=0644
```

the contents should be

```
cat something.conf
#in this comment is the timestamp, format irrelevant
some config lines
```

Do you know any ansible module that can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply add `# {{ ansible_managed }}` to the top of your template.  This variable is [defined in your configuration file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#ansible-managed) to have a default of:

`Ansible managed: {file} modified on %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S by {uid} on {host}`

Note that since this contains a timestamp by default it means that every time your template task is invoked it will update the destination file with the current timestamp.

Comment: Consider updating your answer with the hash prefix to ensure the line is not interpreted as config. In this case, `#{{ ansible_managed }}`

Comment: This is no longer working, new default is `ansible_managed = Ansible managed`

Comment: @kravietz So just change the default value in your ansible.cfg file. It's trivial to change it back to what I quoted above.

Comment: Also use instead `{{ ansible_managed | comment }}`, as this will work with multi-line ansible_managed and the `# {{ ... }}` will only comment the first line